# How to add custom pg_hba.conf to Postgres in Kubernetes docker image

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes

I am trying to deploy Postgres in Kubernetes. I need to add this line at the bottom of pg_hba.conf:

```
host all all all md5
```

to have Postgres accept connections on Kubernetes proxy address.

What is the correct way to do it in the Dockerfile I use to build the image I later use in the kubernetes yaml file?

I have seen this in other Dockerfile, one generating the Postgres docker image from scratch:

```
RUN echo "host all  all    0.0.0.0/0  md5" >> /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf
```

But the resulting file does not include that entry, probably because it is ovewritten buy Postgres when starts up. Any idea what I should do?

Thanks

Clarification: I really don't want the Dockerfile to create another pg_hba.conf in an alternate path and specify it when running the Kubernetes docker, but simply to create a custom one in the standard location for it, for example, in /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf

Comment: It seems to me that the correct path is `/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf`

Comment: What @andolsizied said, or if you were interested, one can [specify an hba_file parameter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/runtime-config-file-locations.html#GUC-HBA-FILE) and point it at a path of your choice

Comment: Thanks... the path in the example I pasted is just from an old tutorial. The question really is on how should I make the Dockerfile to have Postgres create a specific pg_hba.conf in the standard location, not having to put another one in another location and specifying an alternate path for it.